# Conversion of code from vb.net to c#- await task

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, async-await

I have been using the following line of code happily for a while now and it seems to do the job satisfactorily. I am looking to convert it to C#. I am trying to convert:

```
Dim result as string = Await Task(Of String).Factory.StartNew(Function() MyClass.PerformJob(param1,param2,param3))
```

I am entering the following code in C# :

```
string result = await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew((Func<string>) MyClass.PerformJob((param1,param2,param3));
```

This generates the following error:

```
'Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Func<string>'
```

I assume this is related to passing parameters in the way I am; I'm lost as to why this should work in VB.NET and not C#?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast the result of `MyClass.PerformJob` method to `Func<string>` when the result is of type `string`. Use this:

```
string result = await Task<string>.Factory
    .StartNew(() => MyClass.PerformJob(param1,param2,param3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast it to Func, and you likely need to use a lambda to get your parameters into the PerformJob call. Try this.

```
string result = await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => MyClass.PerformJob(param1,param2,param3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace 'MyClass' with 'this' - C# doesn't have a strict equivalent to 'MyClass':

```
string result = await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => this.PerformJob(param1,param2,param3));
```

Comment: Neither does vb.net, it is the name the OP gave a Class that they created. You are thinking of the My Namespace or else Me which is used instead of this.

Comment: No - 'MyClass' is a keyword in VB, with very similar meaning to 'Me', but subtly different.  (Look it up).

Comment: I guess after using Vb.net for over 12 years and having never used it. It must not be that common. Thanks for the information. :)

Comment: You're right - it's not common.  It's one of those "throw in everything but the kitchen sink in case anyone needs it" ideas in the evolution of the VB programming language.

Comment: As mentioned MyClass was simply (in hindsight a bad choice of naming!) the name I gave a class.

Comment: Ok - I'm surprised that VB allowed this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `PerformJob` is a `Func<string>` I dont think you need the `Func<string>` cast.

```
string result = await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(MyClass.PerformJob(param1,param2,param3));
```